# Retrofit request header not received on server in case of real device

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit, interceptor

I am adding and sending headers to retrofit request using interceptors in Android app. See my code below. But request headers do not receive on server when sent from real device but receicve when sent from emulator. I am not able to resolve this issue. Kindly guide what am I doing wrong?

```
private ApiClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
        // add your other interceptors …
        // add logging as last interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        Interceptor jsonInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                String appVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .header("app-version", appVersion)
                        .header("device", "Android")
                        .header("AppPackage", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        };

        httpClient.addInterceptor(jsonInterceptor);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            //analytics logging interceptor for testing only
            Request request = chain.request();
            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return response;
        });

        httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request request = chain.request();
            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            int tryCount = 0;
            int retryLimit = 2;

            while (!response.isSuccessful() && tryCount < retryLimit) {
                tryCount++;
                response.close();
                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }

            return response;
        });

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
```

On the other hand, even I am logging headers but all these headers are not displayed in logcat.

Comment: What do you want with all those interceptors? Remove them. The only place where you have to look/log is at the receiving side. On the server.

Comment: That means as per your comment, headers are added correctly in my code but there seems to be an issue on server side in receiving request headers. Right?

Comment: These interceptors were added before I joined this project. That's the reason I can't remove these at the moment. Do you think retry interceptor is unnecessary here?

Comment: I dont know why you use them. Instead of removing you can just add a new function that does without them.

Comment: What kind of new function. I didn't get your idea actually?

Comment: A function you write. You can add some code to do the same job without those intercepters. If only for testing.

Comment: Try to change interceptors queue. Move header interceptor on the first place, logger interceptor to the last place

Comment: Also recommended use https monitor. Example https://www.charlesproxy.com/. By it you can see all params of your requests